# Ruby on Rails instantiating active record models recursively from a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two classes inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` and a `User` might have many `Badge`s.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to :badges
  has_one :user_info
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_info
end
```

```rb
class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to :users
end
```

When I make an API call for a `User` I get the response below:

```
{
    "UserInfo": {
        "CursePeriod": null,
        "IsCursed": false,
        "IsBanned": false,
    },
    "Badges": [
        {
            "Name": "kayıp",
            "Description": "kim bilir nerede"
        },
        {
            "Name": "çaylak",
            "Description": ""
        }
    ],
    "HasEntryUsedOnSeyler": false,
    "FollowerCount": 0,
    "FollowingsCount": 0,
    "Picture": null
}
```

And when I pass that json as a hash to `User.new` I get

```rb
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Badge(#47159034390540) expected,
got {:name=>"kayıp", :description=>"kim bilir nerede"} which is an instance of Hash(#47159016253160)
```

Is there any way to recursively instantiate all my models from this hash or do I need to do that manually in my `User` class' `initialize` method?

What I've come up with to solve this is:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :badges

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    create_badges(attributes.delete(:badges))
    super
  end

  def create_badges(badges = [])
    @badges = []
    badges.each do |badge|
      @badges << Badge.new(badge)
    end
  end
end
```

I am just asking whether `ActiveRecord` already supports what I am trying to achieve, if so, how?

---

#### **UPDATE**

As for my `UserIdentifier` class, even though I've included `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_info` I still get

```rb
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: UserInfo(#46945688683560) expected,
got {:curse_period=>nil, :is_cursed=>false, :is_banned=>false} which is an instance of Hash(#46945670719200)
```

How I get that error is below

```rb
# The hash that I pass to my User class

hash = {:user_info=>{:curse_period=>nil,
                     :is_cursed=>false,
                     :is_banned=>false},
        :badges=>[{:name=>"kayıp", :description=>"kim bilir nerede"},
                  {:name=>"çaylak", :description=>""}],
        :has_entry_used_on_seyler=>false,
        :follower_count=>0,
        :followings_count=>0,
        :picture=>nil}

# Then simply

User.new(hash)

# After the line above, I get the error I mentioned in my update.
```

Comment: Though not exactly what you need, nested attributes are somewhat similar and may be worth looking into. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I will check that, thank you.

Comment: You must extract the needed data to instantiate a new user from `hash`. You can't pass the whole hash and expect only the needed ones are used, that's why you're getting the error message _... which is an instance of Hash(...)_.

Comment: I just figured I had to use `user_info_attributes` key instead of just `user_info`. Then I don't get that error in the `updated` part.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord doesn't support multiple initializations, meaning you can't pass an array and expect to have multiple instances of a class, because that's what they reflect, `new` is used to instantiate a new object belonging to X class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

What you can do is to use [`create`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-create), which can accept an array of hashes containing the data you want for each record you're creating.

Comment: That sounds better than my approach. So I can simply do `Badge.create` and then pass the array. If that was not an array but only a hash instead, would `accepts_nested_attributes_for` do the work to create a badge? I've been trying that for my other associations but I get the same `AssociationTypeMismatch` error. I can update my question to include that part.

Comment: You can pass an array of hashes and it'll insert the records in the database as long as they're valid and don't throw any error (wrong column names, etc). In the case of a single hash, that's how methods are called in Ruby. `create` will take every key in the hash as the attribute from your model and it's corresponding value, and as before, it'll save the record if it's valid.

Comment: With a single hash like my `UserInfo` in the json response can I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for my `UserInfo` class so that it gets created? I've updated my question to include that part. Can you check it please?

Comment: I see the error, but not why it happens, can you add the whole workaround @AndréYuhai?

Comment: Just added how I try to use the hash to get an instance of `User`. You can see the class definitions at the top of my answer, which already has `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.